# if he arrived two hours ago

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Suppose that I knew John arrived today, but I didn't know exactly when he arrived. Maybe he arrived two hours ago, maybe not. I just wasn't sure. Now consider the following sentence:

> If he arrived two hours ago, he is staying at a hotel now.

> If he arrived two hours ago, he will be staying at a hotel now.

Are both of the above sentences correct? If so, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Both correct, equivalent to each other. I don't see any difference.

Comment: What dialect of English do you speak?

Comment: I'm a native American English speaker. Perhaps we should have signatures that indicate things like this, it often does make a difference.

Comment: @rcook I personally find that questions like this can be a little rude, because I infer there's disagreement in the analysis and some kind of assumption that you must have "got it wrong." It would be better to ask if you're aware of differences in interpretation between regions and dialects of English. (I agree with your answer, and I am unaware of any differences in interpretation.

Comment: I find no rudeness in the question. There are differences, and the person may be just checking answers in general as to provenance. It is possible I don't find it rude because I don't consider these differences "wrong", it's just a matter of culture background, orientation, call it what you will. Meanwhile I'll take a lift to the flat of the girl I fancy.